# Command to get the last command run as String

Tags: cmd, scripting

How can I get the last run command as a string and store it?
say suppose:

```
Step1:XYZ.exe parm1 parm2
step2:If(condition true){do something}
Else {string lstcmd = XYZ.exe parm1 parm2}
```

I need to get the `XYZ.exe parm1 parm2` as a `string`, so that I can use this small piece of code for every command I run.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it as a string, just save it in a variable.

```
SET "THECMD=XYZ.exe parm1 parm2"
%THECMD%
If (condition true) {do something}
Else {ECHO %THECMD%}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks.Looks like this will work for me. Lemme try and will let u know. Thanks!!